# How do you calclulate a file's content_hash for use with Dropbox's API?

Tags: php, dropbox-api

I need to verify the content of local file copy against the copy on Dropbox. I'm getting that information via a request to the API v2's `get_metadata` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function dropbox_content_hash($file) {
    $fh = fopen($file, 'r');
    if (!$fh) {
        # warning already issued
        return;
    }
    $hashes = '';
    $zero_byte_exception_check = true;
    do {
        $chunk = fread($fh, 4194304);
        if ($zero_byte_exception_check) {
            if ($chunk === '') {
                return 'e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855';
            }
            $zero_byte_exception_check = false;
        }
        $hashes .= hash('sha256', $chunk, true);
    } while (!feof($fh));
    fclose($fh);
    return hash('sha256', $hashes);
}
```

Comment: @AlexanderKucheryuk The question states [the relevant API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-get_metadata) which it seems you didn't read. Note that responses contain a field like `"content_hash": "e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855"` That important field is mentioned ~100 times on that page. I'm sorry you had trouble reading the code, I thought it was self-explanatory, especially `$zero_byte_exception_check` (a file with 0 bytes uses only the hash of the empty string). FYVM for the downvote instead of suggesting an edit.

Comment: @AlexanderKucheryuk You've conflated logical fallacy with taking exception to your position. You literally clicked on a button that has the title **This answer is not useful** when (a) that's obviously not the case, and (b) you've offered nothing in the way of time or effort to link to or produce anything else of value. At the time, I couldn't find an implementation of their algorithm in procedural PHP, I thought (and still think) it was better to quickly share my solution than to keep it to myself. How you can think `function dropbox_content_hash($file)` is not "self-contained" is beyond me.